# Tools for a timetable calendar in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I am making a web application which is a scheduler for school work, and part of it is a calendar in a working week Mon-Fri / Mon-Sun timetable view.

The user will plan sessions, and then I need them to appear like appointments on a timetable, kind of like Microsoft Outlook does. So I need a calendar which I can write events to and display them.

Can anybody recommend any JavaScript or HTML5/CSS tools, frameworks or approaches I should take for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/. I use the Calendar module, nice and complete.